# s3.copyObject does not apply ServerSideEncryption to object in target bucket?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to perform cross-account backups of any objects from one bucket on `ACCOUNT-A` to a backup bucket on `ACCOUNT-B` and I want the objects in the backup bucket to be encrypted using `AES256`. But the encryption doesn't seem to be getting applied to the objects that land in the backup bucket.

**The Setup**

- `ACCOUNT-A` has a source bucket called `assets.myapp.com`
- `ACCOUNT-B` has a target bucket called `backup-assets.myapp.com`
- An `s3.ObjectCreated:*` bucket event on the `assets.myapp.com` bucket triggers a Lambda function to copy the newly created object to the `backup-assets.myapp.com` bucket under `ACCOUNT-B`.
- Attempting to apply `ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'` to the objects in the `backup-assets.myapp.com` bucket once they land there.

**The Lambda Function Code**

```
var async = require('async');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

exports.backupObject = function backupS3Object(event, context) {

    if (event.Records === null) {
        return context.fail('NOTICE:', 'No records to process.');
    }

    async.each(event.Records, function(record, iterate) {

        var sourceBucket = record.s3.bucket.name;
        var targetBucket = 'backup-' + record.s3.bucket.name;
        var key = record.s3.object.key;

        s3.copyObject({
            Bucket : targetBucket,
            CopySource : sourceBucket + '/' + key,
            Key : key,
            ACL : 'private',
            ServerSideEncryption : 'AES256',
            MetadataDirective : 'COPY',
            StorageClass : 'STANDARD_IA'
        }, function(error, data) {

            if (error) return iterate(error);
            console.log('SSE: ' + data.ServerSideEncryption);
            console.log('SUCCESS: Backup of ' + sourceBucket + '/' + key);
            return iterate();

        });

    }, function (error) {

        if (error) {
            return context.fail('ERROR:', 'One or more objects could not be copied.');
        }

        return context.done();

    });

};
```

**Cloudwatch Log Reports Success**

When the function runs, the object is successfully copied, and the Cloudwatch Log for my Lambda function reports the `ServerSideEncryption` used as `AES256`.

**However, The S3 Console Disagrees**

But the problem is that when I inspect the `Properties > Details` of the copied object in the `backup-assets.myapp.com` bucket under `ACCOUNT-B` it reports `Server Side Encryption: None`.

Any idea why the `SSE` doesn't seem to be applied to the object when it lands in the `backup-assets.myapp.com` bucket? Or is it actually being applied and I've just discovered a display bug in the `S3 Console`?

> **BONUS QUESTION**
>
> When I attempt to apply `SSE:AES256` to any given object manually
>   using the console, I get the following error: `The additional
>   properties (RRS/SSE) were not enabled or disabled due to errors for
>   the following objects in backup-assets.myapp.com:
>   copied-object-one.txt.`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is this the case on ALL objects copied? How big are the objects? [This old forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93744) suggests you might have problems above 5GB. Have you considered using [Cross-Region Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) to do the copy for you automatically (requires versioning)?

Comment: hey John, objects range from 20k to 1Gb. Cross-region replication doesn't meet my task goals, needs to be x-account. Both buckets do have versioning enabled though. I'm 90% certain it's an issue with how the S3 console presents the encrypted status of any given object. I've done some more testing and I'm seeing the same issue — sometimes — when I just upload an object into a standalone bucket without versioning and use the console to encrypt it. It's either a bug, or yet another AWS feature-bug, haven't figured out which yet.

Comment: Cross-region replication *can* be done between buckets that belong to **different accounts** (it just requires the right security setup). Another alternative would be to use the `aws s3 sync` command in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) on a regular schedule (eg every 5 minutes). This could be run in a Lambda task scheduled via CloudWatch Events or from a `cron` job somewhere.

Comment: I did not know that. I'll look into x-account x-region replication now then. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Okay, so how does one go about getting a bucket on `ACCOUNT-B` listed in the console under `ACCOUNT-A`? Or does this need to be done via the CLI? If you were to write-up a working solution to this as answer I can see it being accepted as very helpful.

Comment: Okay, so I found the AWS tutorial on setting up X-Acccont replication, and managed to get it working. BUT, still the same problem. When I upload a file into `ACCOUNT-A` and set SSE it doesn't get replicated to the target bucket. Tutorial followed is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-walkthrough-2.html

Comment: To clarify, the encryption doesn't get replicated to the object that lands in the target bucket, the object *does* replicate, but does not get encrypted. Or, at least the S3 console doesn't indicate that it's encrypted.

Comment: This just keeps getting crazier. So some further testing has revealed that the encryption *will* be copied, but *only* if you set the object ACL to "Public". What. The. Fudge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out.

The problem was with the `ACL` parameter of the `copyObject` method.

If you want to use `ServerSideEnryption: 'AES256'` on the objects that land in the target bucket you *must* provide an ACL that allows `bucket-owner-full-control` to allow your backup bucket to apply the encryption. This is not documented anywhere (that I found), but I've done extensive testing now (not by choice) and determined that this does work. So the working Lambda function code is below:

```
var async = require('async');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

exports.backupObject = function backupS3Object(event, context) {

    if (event.Records === null) {
        return context.done('NOTICE: No records to process.');
    }

    async.each(event.Records, function(record, iterate) {

        var sourceBucket = record.s3.bucket.name;
        var targetBucket = 'backup-' + record.s3.bucket.name;
        var key = record.s3.object.key;

        s3.copyObject({
            Bucket : targetBucket,
            CopySource : sourceBucket + '/' + key,
            Key : key,
            ACL : 'bucket-owner-full-control',
            ServerSideEncryption : 'AES256',
            MetadataDirective : 'COPY',
            StorageClass : 'STANDARD_IA'
        }, function(error, data) {

            if (error) return iterate(error);
            console.log('SUCCESS: Backup of ' + sourceBucket + '/' + key);
            return iterate();

        });

    }, function (error) {

        return context.done(error);

    });

};
```

I'm not sure if this is possible using the X-region X-account replication method discussed in the comments in the question above. There doesn't seem to be any way to declare `SSE` when performing a replication.